# r rename objects of lists

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have below code. It takes a dataframe and splits it into multiple parts using values in a column. For the new dataframes I would like to have custom name that will be equal something like 26*Z where 26 is a serial number, * is a wildcard character and Z is the old name. But the below code is not working :(

```
x = data.frame(num = 1:26, let = letters, LET = LETTERS)
x1=split(x, x$LET)
x1$A
class(x1)
names(x1[1])


for (i in 1:length(x1))
{


names(x1[i])=paste0(sprintf("%02d", i),"*",names(x1[1]))
}


names(x1[i])="26*Z"
```

Comment: `setNames(x1, nm = paste(1:length(x1),"*",names(x1),sep=""))`

Comment: similarly: `names(x1) <- paste0(1:length(x1), "*", names(x1))`